# System.DllNotFoundException for sqlite3

Tags: .net, sqlite, uwp

I have installed Microsoft.Data.Sqlite Nuget package of version 1,1,1 (Because i have visual studio 2015 and 2.0.0 is not supported in it). Everything works fine in x86 and x64 but the problem comes for the arm version when i deploy the app th my mobile it throes the following exception

An exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to load DLL 'sqlite3': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

This is my stack trace

```
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Interop.NativeMethods.Sqlite3_sqlite3.sqlite3_open_v2(IntPtr filename, Sqlite3Handle& ppDb, Int32 flags, IntPtr vfs)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Interop.NativeMethods.Sqlite3_sqlite3.open_v2(IntPtr filename, Sqlite3Handle& ppDb, Int32 flags, IntPtr vfs)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Interop.NativeMethods.sqlite3_open_v2(String filename, Sqlite3Handle& ppDb, Int32 flags, String vfs)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Interop.NativeMethods.OnLoad()
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Interop.NativeMethods.get_Sqlite3()
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Interop.NativeMethods.sqlite3_open_v2(String filename, Sqlite3Handle& ppDb, Int32 flags, String vfs)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.Open()
   at MyTodoData.functions..ctor()
   at My_Todo.MainPage..ctor()
   at My_Todo.My_Todo_XamlTypeInfo.XamlTypeInfoProvider.Activate_0_MainPage()
   at My_Todo.My_Todo_XamlTypeInfo.XamlUserType.ActivateInstance()
```

My phone is lumia 640 running 15254.1

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue with `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` Nuget package of version 1.1.1. You could try to clean  and rebuild your solution  or reverse the Microsoft.Data.Sqlite NuGet package to version 1.1.0.

Comment: Even the problem looks wired for me. it is happen only with phone. I tried building appx file and installing even then the app doesn't open.

Comment: Will it be problem with my mobile phone?

Comment: May be you could try to deploy to other phone. I test with lumia 950.

Comment: Reset the phone but still no use

Comment: Could you show more code?

Comment: Am i missing any dependency? Nuget package should install everything automatically i guess.

Comment: Yep, it will install dependency automatically.

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Atyl9LF4coKCjvFaJopuNm7O4XqCNw  Download it from here

Comment: Ok，I will check.

Comment: I have deployed to lumia 950 successfully. I guess the NuGet Cache  cause the issue, you could clean the cache with visual studio tools, and you could clean the cache folder manually. Please refer to [Managing the NuGet cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-nuget-cache)

Comment: Let me know the result.

Comment: Still same. Can you Build the the project and send? if it works i will repair my visual studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the line

```
SqliteEngine.UseWinSqlite3();
```

or

```
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Internal.SqliteEngine.UseWinSqlite3();
```

Has solved the issue.

The x86 and x64 versions have built in sqlite3.dll but it is not present in ARM devices.

Newer devices like Lumia 950 or 950xl might have the package but the older device like lumia 640 doesn't have.

According to this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases) After Fall creators update you should be able to use SQLite without any extra binaries. My phone had fall creators update but the target version of project was Anniversary Update.

Now it uses the Sqlite engine provided with nuget rather than the System installed one.